# addClass not working for specific id of a textarea

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class `mceBasicEditor` to a textarea with `id="abcd"` so that the tinymce Toolbar will load when that class is present in the textarea tag. But when click the check box I get the alert but on checking the text area, I see that the class `mceBasicEditor` has not been added nor has the tinymce toolbar appeared.

This is the code for the checkbox:

```
<form><input type="checkbox" id="mceCheck" name="mceCheck" value="1" >mce Toggle</form>
```

Here is the text area:

```
<p id="description" style=""><label style=""  class="leftLabel" >Event Description</label><textarea name="event_description" id="abcd" style="" rows="25" cols="50" class="contact  mceNoEditor "></textarea></p>
```

Jqueru for adding the class:

```
$('#mceCheck').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        alert(1);
        $('#abcd').addClass('mceBasicEditor');
    }
    else
    {
        alert(0);
        $('#abcd').removeClass('mceBasicEditor');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you the fiddle works and the class, but for some reason it is not working on my web page. Do you have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope nothing, everything works fine. I just can't seem to add the class.

Comment: Weird...what browser?

Comment: I got it, as usual, a small error. I had tried it on a different text area and forgot to remove the ID from that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this instead (to add/remove `class`)

```
$(function(){
    $('#mceCheck').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#abcd').addClass('mceBasicEditor');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#abcd').removeClass('mceBasicEditor');
        }
    });
});
```

[**Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QkY6G/1/)

**Update :**
Also, `toggleClass` will work

```
$(function(){
    $('#mceCheck').change(function(){
        $('#abcd').toggleClass('mceBasicEditor');
    });
});
```

[**Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QkY6G/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$(this).attr('checked')
```

Use:

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

From jQuery's `.prop()` documentation:

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

Comment: I used that, but it doesn't seem to really change anything. Everything is working the same way as it would've with `attr`.